# storing value in app.config for console application

Tags: c#

I am going to developer the console application which run some service to move file from one location to other. and in UI i will the total size of file till moved .so i am storing the value in console like below

```
 <appSettings>
   <add key="fileSize" value="20002">
 </appSettings>
```

So when service stopped or system restarted. i will use this value when console application started again

**My Question**

Is this correct standard to store value in config like above?

Comment: IMO, yes.  It's a lot cleaner than declaring it within the code (potentially in several places).

Comment: "webconfig" as in "a ".config" file? Normally "web.config" used for ASP.Net sites - somewhat confusing to try to use it somehow for console app...

Comment: sorry exactly in app.config.I will give this console service to my customer. Is it proper way to do it ?  Is there any other better way do it ?

Comment: It sounds like you need to write the value, not just read it, correct? It doesn't make much sense for you to know all files will be one size. I would recommend using Settings in the project properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. you can read it trying something like this:

```
int fizeSize = int.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fileSize"]);
```

Remember to add the reference for `System.Configuration` if your program does not find it.

Comment: I would use TryParse and would check first, if the value for fileSize exists and is not null.

Answer (score 0):

Add References(System.Configuration) in your console app. and use mention line in you .cs file

```
String fileSize = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fileSize "];
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to other answers, but per this Microsoft article:

[Create a Console Application That Reads the Content of a Configuration File](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/815786/how-to-store-and-retrieve-custom-information-from-an-application-confi)

```
string fileSize = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("fileSize");
```

If the key doesn't exist or the key's `value=""`, the returned value will be `null`.